# scraping "View more" button with scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the data from this page https://hipages.com.au/find/electricians/wa/perth, but there is a "view more" button. And I don't know which url to use for the more data.

I inspected the page, opened the network tab, but I was unable to find a good way to scrape all the data with Scrapy.

I know I can use Selenium, but there are more then 200 000 urls, so I can not use Selenium for this, because it would take weeks to get all the data.

Answer (score 2):

The website uses an API, therefore you could use it.
Ex: https://hipages.com.au/api/directory/sites?suburb=perth&state=wa&category=8&page=1&perpage=10&code=111d887415230e233b23fdaae8e160d62715d99d7c417a33c1ca27c0b47b3a6ce810db7af2cec77fe5a629d12ad9cc68

You can then manipulate the query parameters of the url and then fetch the data via Scrapy.

Comment: I found thiis, but I don't know how to create url and how to get code from query string parameters

Comment: You can get the string parameters from a url using: `urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(random_url).query)`

Comment: this can not solve my problem, because I can not make new url

Comment: The url is just a string. You can build it by using basic string formatting or using the urllib I mentioned. Here is an example of both options: https://repl.it/repls/FineValuableGlobalarrays

Comment: i have this url https://hipages.com.au/find/electricians/wa/perth, so how to find this url https://hipages.com.au/api/directory/sites?suburb=perth&state=wa&category=8&page=1&perpage=10&code=111d887415230e233b23fdaae8e160d62715d99d7c417a33c1ca27c0b47b3a6ce810db7af2cec77fe5a629d12ad9cc68 on the page ?